# PHP & MySQL - When to launch a website

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering when I finish coding my site what are somethings I should check for before I launch my site.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72394/what-should-a-developer-know-before-building-a-public-web-site

Comment: This is no way to ask a question btw - you should at least tell us what you've tought of already, prove that you made some effort. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask please.

Comment: @Konerak, Its a legit question and I think coding a whole website is at least some effort.

Comment: You really didn't read the link? Try at least explaining what you did already (except for coding).

Comment: @Konerak, that is what I'm asking what should I look for before going live?

Answer (score 3):

[Remember to remove your test alerts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/lol-debugging-are-we-so-homepage-alerts-false)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [good list](http://boagworld.com/business-strategy/pre-launch-checklist/) to check out.

A few other things are:

- make sure your live environment has all the modules, etc that you used in dev.
- have 'blank slates' for when people first start using it.
- have a few people you trust go over it and try to break it.
- [link checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink/)
- if possible run the live version on a subdomain if the live site already exists to ensure all is good.

Don't get too bogged down in the details though.  Get it out there and tweak/iterate as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Before launching a site there is an infinite amount of things to check for (thus the reason for so many security updates in free scripts, etc.). That said, nothing is perfect and totally bug free and, therefore, should not scare you from making your site live (although you must be diligent in fixing issues when they are found).

To narrow down the list, I would take a step back and reflect on the purpose of your site (e.g. are you a service provider or a product provider?) Other questions to ask include whether you will be storing (important?) client data, and are there other concerns you may have about content.

If you will be holding sensitive client data, I would highly recommend checking for any login vulnerabilities (for instance, if someone can spoof into the "admin" account or what have you) or if your database is exposed in anyway. I have heard of developers hiring other developers to try to hack their sites (although I've never done this myself), but that may perhaps be an option for you if you don't have much security experience since security is such a sensitive topic and high-liability area.

Outside of general security, I would make sure all of your general content is well protected. This goes along with proper CHMOD permissions on certain files and directories (generally speaking, 0644 for files and 0755 for directories). Also, have some sort of backup system in place (whether automatic or manual, you'll want to back up frequently).

Now, if you're providing a product, you should ask yourself how easily your software/product can be duplicated and/or can other users easily use one copy for multiple users. If this is the case, you should look into securing your downloads section or the software/product itself so that it is more unique (this is much easier said than done).

Hope this helps.

Good luck!
Dennis M.